# Finalizar de forma programática aplicación SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Necesito **finalizar programáticamente** una aplicación **SpringBoot** sin finalizar la instancia o task donde esta la aplicación, para luego volver a iniciarla por medio de un evento

En otras palabras, que es lo contrario de arrancar SpringBoot:

```
new SpringApplication(Main.class).run(args);
```

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que lo que estás tratando de lograr es apagar el contexto de spring-boot. Si inspeccionamos el método `run()`

```java
public static ConfigurableApplicationContext run(Class<?> primarySource, String... args) {
    return run(new Class[]{primarySource}, args);
}
```

Notamos que devuelve `ConfigurableApplicationContext` que sería el contexto de la aplicación o `ApplicationContext`, por lo que podrías cerrar dicho contexto con `close()` y volver a levantarlo con `start()`:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
        // apagar
        ctx.close();
        // volver a correr
        ctx.start();
    }
}
```

Te dejo esta [documentación/guia](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-shutdown) y esta [otra](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-context-events) que me ayudo a validar los ejemplos.